# Computing A Specific Generating Function Sequence

Tags: sequences, power-series

http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/A097196

I was wondering how to continue generating the sequence given in the link.  It is based off a generating function.  Any ideas would be appreciated.  Certain numbers in a certain sequence of this sequence are showing up as answers to subproblems of Project Euler [problem 208](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=208) (robot walks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting a Generating Function to an implementation that actually spits out the elements of a series is not trivial.  If you use Mathematica, there are some built-in functions to handle this.  A description can be found at [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneratingFunction.html).

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that sequence defined by the function at the top of the page -- `{n >= 1} (1+q^(3*n))^4*(1-q^(3*n))^2/(1-q^(2*n))` ? Just keep running the function, no?

Comment: I guess I need to clarify my question.  How do I implement the function at the top of the page in the programming language of your choice?  That's were I am stuck.